# how can i capture null values from mssql_result?

Tags: php, sql-server, null

I am running a query

```
$Health = mssql_query("Select 
*
from
Health
where 
HEA_ID = '$HEA_ID'
");
```

and then capturing one of the fields here:

```
$HEA_DocsOnFile = mssql_result($Health,0,'HEA_DocsOnFile');
```

the field `HEA_DocsOnFile` is a `bit` in `sql server`

**how do i know whether `HEA_DocsOnFile` is a `NULL` or a `0`?**

unfortunately `mssql_result` returns the same value for `NULL` and `0`!

i've also tried:

```
$HEA_DocsOnFile = is_null(mssql_result($Health,0,'HEA_DocsOnFile')) ? null : mssql_result($Health,0,'HEA_DocsOnFile');
```

to make sure to set `$HEA_DocsOnFile` to `null`

and later to check a checkbox if it's 0 and NOT NULL this way:

```
<?php if($HEA_DocsOnFile===0)  { echo  'checked="checked"' ; }?>
```

even though it is indeed null (as sql server says at least), it still checks the checkbox thinking that it is `0`

**update**
per marc's suggestion, i explicitly selected all the columns instead of doing `select *`

i did:

```
select
....
 ,[HEA_POLST]
      ,[HEA_MOST]
      ,[HEA_DNR]
      ,isnull(HEA_DocsOnFile,2) HEA_DocsOnFile
from...........
```

i know that `HEA_DocsOnFile` is now `2`

however, when testing:

```
<?php if($HEA_DocsOnFile==1)  { echo  'checked="checked"' ; }?>
```

it actually checks the box!

what am i doing wrong?

i actually did a `var_dump($HEA_DocsOnFile);` and it returned `int(1)`

how can that be? it is **NULL** in sql server!!

i even did:

```
select............
    ,isnull(HEA_DocsOnFile,'2') HEA_DocsOnFile
```

to change the type from `int` to `string` and then did a `var_dump` and it **STILL RETURNED** `int(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to cut my losses and just change the schema of that annoying field from `bit` to `tinyint`!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's an actual zero? Remember php's loose comparison rules:

```
php > $x = null;
php > var_dump($x == 0);     // simple quality test
bool(true)
php > var_dump(is_null($x)); // best way to check for nulls
bool(true)
php > var_dump($x === 0);    // strict equality test
bool(false)
php > var_dump($x === null);
bool(true)
php > var_dump($x == null);
bool(true)
php >
```

Comment: thanks! is this how i would check a checkbox if it's 0 and NOT null if($HEA_DocsOnFile==0 && !(is_null($HEA_DocsOnFile))  { echo  'checked="checked"' ; }?>

Comment: you're checking the checkbox the field value in the db is false? seems kind of backwards.

Comment: hahah. there's a YES and a NO checkbox, i'm working right now on the NO checkbox. i dont want the NO checkbox to be checked if the db has a NULL value

Comment: better to use radio buttons for a yes/no choice, but that's up to you. basically you'd want `if ($bitfield === 1) { checked }` for the YES box, and `if ($bitfield === 0) { checked }` for the NO box. don't check anything if the field's null, because null in a database context corresponds to "unknown". it'd be incorrect to check either box because you have no information at all whether that null is "truthy" or "falsey".

Comment: i want to keep checkboxes because i want the user to have the ability to not check anything (and if they mistakenly select a radio button, this wont be possible)

Comment: if the mssql library is indeed returning an actual integer 0 for null fields, you might have to bite the bullet and select a derived `IFNULL(yourfield, -1)` or something and test for that value.

Comment: last question, according to your answer, in the same way that we use the triple equality ===, is there a !== as well?

Comment: well marc, i know that it is returning 2, because i did isnull(..., 2), and for some reason the YES checkbox is still checked: <?php if($HEA_DocsOnFile==1)  { echo  'checked="checked"' ; }?>

Comment: :) give up and think im crazy?

Comment: by the way marc, why did you delete all of your comments!???? they were useful to me!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
ISNULL ( HEA_DocsOnFile , NULL )
```